# Como guardar multiples registros en base de datos C# +SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Mi duda es tengo una pantalla, donde antes se recolectaban 5 valores.

```
Insertar(this.ListVehiculo.Text, this.ListConductor.Text, this.ListResponsable.Text,
                     this.documentos.Text, this.obDocumentos.Text)
```

Pero ahora tengo que recolectar los valores de 40 campos mas, es optimo llenar ese metodo con los 40 campos adicionales?
En mi base de datos pensaba en una tabla con los conceptos y otra con los resultados.
Así

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblprueba]
           ([Fecha]
           ,[idItem]
           ,[idConcepto]
           ,[Detalle]
           ,[Observacion])
     VALUES
           (Valores)
```

Ahora la mejor forma de mandar los parametros desde c# es con todos los 40 campos en el metodo o de que otra forma se puede realizar?

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Lo ideal sería crear algún viewModel o clase especifica que contenga esos valores, y en tu método insertar sólo pases como parámetro dicha clase

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Me puedes regalar un ejemplo por favor

Comment: Estas trabajando con MVC?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Si señor asp.net con mvc

Comment: Puedes usar 'EntityFramework', Crear una entidad de tu tabla automáticamente y utilizar esta para guardar los datos.

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo hola, me puedes regalar un ejemplo usando EntityFramework por favor

Answer (score 1):

Como te indique en los comentarios, una manera óptima es crear algún tipo de clase que contenga tus propiedades, por lo que al momento de utilizar la función en tu controlador | servicio, etc. Pidas solamente dicha clase.

Por ejemplo si deseamos ingresar una nueva persona a nuestra BD, creamos una clase con las propiedades correspondientes:

```
public class Persona
{
   public string Nombre { get; set; }
   public string Apellido { get; set; }
   public int Edad { get; set; }
}
```

y cuando utilicemos nuestro controlador, lo usamos así:

```
public ActionResult Agregar(Persona item)
{
  // Código...
  return View();
}
```

Ahora adaptándome un poco a tu ejemplo, veo que tienes un método **Insertar(para1, para2...)**, por lo que deberías cambiarlo por algo asi

```
Insertar(Persona p)
```

Y dentro de ese método *Insertar*, podrías agregar cada valor de esta forma:

```
public bool Insertar(Persona item)
{
   db.Add(item);
   return context.SaveChanges() > 0
}
```

Este método te devuelve un true o false dependiendo si ingreso o no el elemento en tu `BD`.

**Destaco obviamente que la adaptación es mera suposición de lo que publicaste, ya que ignoro si estás utilizando N Capas.**

De esta forma ahorras especificar parámetro por parámetro y a la vez construyes un sistema mucho más **fácil de mantener** y **orientado a objetos**.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tienes una tabla con 20 registros (pueden ser mas):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1- Cree la Bd con la tabla de la imagen anterior.  BD = Ejemplo, Tabla= TablaEjemplo

2- Cree un proyecto nuevo de MVC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3- Agregue un proyecto nuevo (tipo libreria o biblioteca de clases), que sera la capa de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4- Agregue un nuevo elemento a la capa Datos, de tipo ADO.NET Entity Data Model

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Seleccione le tipo de modelo Code First desde base de datos, tambien peude ser EF Designer, al seleccionar desde base de datos nos permite seleccionar las entidades desde la BD:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para eso hay que seleccionar la conexion a la Bd antes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccione los objetos de la Bd que tendra mi modelo de Entity:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle finalizar se crean automáticamente el objeto Model que es mi context (El que interactua con la Base de datos) de base de datos, el cual contiene toda la definición de los objetos que seleccione y es como el motor de Entity Framework.

Adicionado al Model se creara una clase por cada objeto de la base de datos seleccionado en el asistente, en este caso: TablaEjemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Model.cs

```
namespace MvcEjemplo.Datos
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public partial class Model : DbContext
{
    public Model()
        : base("name=ModelContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TablaEjemplo> TablaEjemplo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo1)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo2)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo3)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo4)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo5)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo6)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo7)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo8)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo9)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo10)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo11)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo12)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo13)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo14)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo15)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo16)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo17)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo18)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo19)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TablaEjemplo>()
            .Property(e => e.Campo20)
            .IsFixedLength();
    }
}
}
```

TablaEjemplo.cs

```
namespace MvcEjemplo.Datos
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("TablaEjemplo")]
public partial class TablaEjemplo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo3 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo4 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo5 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo6 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo7 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo8 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo9 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo10 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo11 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo12 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo13 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo14 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo15 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo16 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo17 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo18 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo19 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Campo20 { get; set; }
}
}
```

5- Agregue un nuevo proyecto Servicios, el cual sera la capa de interacción con la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Agregue la referencia de MvcEjemplo.Datos a MvcEjemplo.Servicios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Agregue la clase TablaEjemploService al proyecto  MvcEjemplo.Servicios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6- Le di click derecho a la solución y seleccione administrar Nugets, para agregar Entity Framework a la capa Servicios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TablaEjemploService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MvcEjemplo.Datos;

namespace MvcEjemplo.Servicios
{
public class TablaEjemploService
{
    public TablaEjemplo SelectById(int id)
    {
        using (var db = new Model())
        {
            //Consulto solo el primer dato donde le id coincida
            return db.TablaEjemplo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }

    public List<TablaEjemplo> Select()
    {
        using (var db = new Model())
        {
            //Consulto todos los datos de la tablaEjemplo
            return db.TablaEjemplo.ToList();
        }
    }

    public void Insert(TablaEjemplo info)
    {
        using (var db = new Model())
        {
            //Aqui el entity hace el insert
            db.TablaEjemplo.Add(info);
            //Con esta instruccion se envian los cambios a la BD
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void Update(TablaEjemplo info)
    {
        using (var db = new Model())
        {
            var query = db.TablaEjemplo.Where(x => x.Id == info.Id);

            //Si encontro el registro.... lo actualizo
            if (query.Any())
            {
                var infoToUpdate = query.FirstOrDefault();
                //Se podria usar automapper o algun plugin por el estilo  para pasar los datos de info a infoToUpdate
                infoToUpdate.Campo = info.Campo;
                infoToUpdate.Campo1 = info.Campo1;
                infoToUpdate.Campo2 = info.Campo2;
                infoToUpdate.Campo3 = info.Campo3;
                infoToUpdate.Campo4 = info.Campo4;//Solo pongo estos datos para el ejemplo

                //Con esta instruccion se envian los cambios a la BD
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

7- Agregue la referencias de Datos y Servicios al proyecto de Mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

8- En el web.Config del proyecto MVC debemos agregar la conexion a la BD, sugiero copiarlo del app.config de la capa Datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

9- Agregue un nuevo Controller al proyecto MvcEjemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- En un principio este controller solo tiene el Action Index, le podemos dar click drecho al View del return y agregar la vista para este controller.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí seleccionamos template LIST, Model = La entidad TablaEjemplo del proyecto Datos y Data context = Lo dejamos en blanco

- Con esto visual creara la vista para Index:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Debemos pasarle el model en el controller para que funcione:

  ```
  // GET: TablaEjemplo
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
      //Consultar la informacion de TablaEjemplo
      TablaEjemploService service = new TablaEjemploService();
      var datos = service.Select();
      return View(datos);
  }
  ```

  Agregue los demas actions:

Podemos agregar las vistas de la misma manera, click derecho en View, seleccionamos Create u Edit según sea el caso y elegimos el modelo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Create (Debe existir un post=[Enviar los datos] y un get):

  ```
  // GET: TablaEjemplo/Create
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
      return View();
  }

  // POST: TablaEjemplo/Create
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(TablaEjemplo info)
  {
      try
      {
          //Llamo al servicio para insertar datos
          TablaEjemploService service = new TablaEjemploService();
          service.Insert(info);

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      catch
      {
          return View();
      }
  }
  ```
- Edit  (Debe existir un post=[Enviar los datos] y un get):

  ```
  // GET: TablaEjemplo/Edit/5
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
  {
      //Obtengo por id el valor a editarse
      TablaEjemploService service = new TablaEjemploService();
      var info = service.SelectById(id);
      return View(info);
  }

  // POST: TablaEjemplo/Edit/5
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Edit(int id, TablaEjemplo info)
  {
      try
      {
          //Llamo al servicio para actualizar datos
          TablaEjemploService service = new TablaEjemploService();
          info.Id = id;
          service.Update(info);

          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      catch
      {
          return View();
      }
  }
  ```

Al correr la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podemos quitar campos del Index View para que se vea la columna de acciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Información en la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Script para crear la tabla, si quieres probar el ejemplo:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TablaEjemplo]    Script Date: 11/12/2018 11:19:13 a. m.   ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TablaEjemplo](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Campo] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo1] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo2] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo3] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo4] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo5] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo6] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo7] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo8] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo9] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo10] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo11] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo12] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo13] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo14] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo15] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo16] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo17] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo18] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo19] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Campo20] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TablaEjemplo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,             ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Y por ultimo te anexo el código fuente del ejemplo:

[MvcEjemplo Codigo Fuente](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nwR5UCLks0paJ-JqeHOpFsUCK_ku0kNf)